# PowerBI - one filter for multiple datasets

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Full disclosure, I am a powerBI n00b. I am working on a report for data generated by an external system. This system exports data into different tabs in an excel sheet(lame, I know). I am needing to get a single filter to filter data from all 4 data sets. Let's say this column is "last name". I have tried to create these relationships, and it seems to work....however I am convinced this is not the proper way to handle this.

- Dataset1.Lastname --> Dataset2.Lastname
- Dataset2.Lastname --> Dataset3.Lastname
- Dataset3.Lastname --> Dataset4.Lastname

Cardinality of Many to Many, and a cross filter direction of both for each relationship

**Alternatively, I read about creating a new table [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007653/one-slicer-for-power-bi-desktop-affecting-multiple-tables), so I also tried this:**

```
Lastname = DISTINCT(
            UNION(
                VALUES('Dataset1'[Lastname]),
                VALUES('Dataset2'[Lastname]),
                VALUES('Dataset3'[Lastname]), 
                VALUES('Dataset4'[Lastname]))
            )
        )
```

And created similar relationships above, with cardinality of many to many and cross filter direction of both.

Does anyone know of a better way? Thanks in advance(and I apologize for being obtuse)!

Answer (score 1):

Power BI works best when the data is in a format called a "Star Schema". Your 4 tabs are likely "Fact tables" and you need a "Dimension table" to do the filtering you need.

So, yes, create the Lastname table. On the link you referenced, yes, there will be a problem setting up the relationships if there is a null Lastname, so if that's a thing in your data, you'll have to filter it out.

When you set up the relationships, they should be One to Many and filter in a single direction. When you use Lastname in your reports or slicers, always use it from the Lastname table, never from the the 4 Fact tables. It is best practice to hide Lastname in those 4 tables from the Model page.

Rarely should you use Many to Many or filtering in Both directions. If you are, it's often a sign that your data is modeled incorrectly. I would ask questions here before using either setting until you are more familiar with data modeling in a Star Schema.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I am researching now.  It seems that I need to go FACT * --> 1 DIM.  Where this is breaking down a bit, is that more or less, these different datasets all have the same columns.  Basically the same data based on different dates across the 4 data sets.  Does the star schema still apply?

Comment: Made some changes, and here is what I did. Still needed to do this to populate the fact table.: 

Lastname = DISTINCT(
            UNION(
                VALUES('Dataset1'[Lastname]),
                VALUES('Dataset2'[Lastname]),
                VALUES('Dataset3'[Lastname]), 
                VALUES('Dataset4'[Lastname]))
            )
        ) 

then I did:


Dataset1.Lastname:many --> 1:fact.Lastname 
Dataset2.Lastname:many --> 1:fact.Lastname
Dataset3.Lastname:many --> 1:fact.Lastname
Dataset4.Lastname:many --> 1:fact.Lastname

Comment: If the data is the same columns just a different value in the date column, use Power Query and append the 4 files into one table. Your dimension then is a date table. Lots out there on Google on creating a date table and why you want one. Between slicers/filters and time dimension DAX functions, almost every model has at least one date dimension.